# Markov Process, Markov Chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I am trying to explain the differences between the following concepts to someone and I realized I myself am super confused:

Continuous/discrete Markov Process

Continuous/Discrete Markov chains

Markov property : $P\{X_n=i|X_{n-1}=j,X_{n-2}=k,...\}=P\{X_n=i|X_{n-1}=j\}$ ?

I used to think: Every process that has Markov property is a Markov Process. 
Every Markov process is a Markov chain and every Markov chain is a Markov process.

But it seems crazy now when I think about it, because if they are all the same, why there are different names for them?

And they are continuous (discrete) if their parameter set $T$ is continuous (discrete) regardless of their state space?

I want to start with homogeneous Markov chain and process too. But since I am already too confused and Wikipedia is making me more confused, I prefer to wait till I get these basic definitions straight first.

Also if anyone has any suggestions on how to explain these terms w/o causing any confusion I would appreciate it a lot. (I would also contact my SP teacher to teach him that, coz he has clearly taught us bad)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before adding the Markov property, I think it helps to distinguish between [discrete time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_stochastic_process) and [continuous time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous-time_stochastic_process) stochastic processes with discrete or continuous state spaces.  (This classification of stochastic processes is nicely summarized [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_process#Classification).) Suppose that $(S,\Sigma)$ is a measurable space and $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ is a given [probability space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space).  Then an $S$-valued [stochastic process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_process) is a family of $S$-valued random variables $X_t$ parametrized by a time-like variable $t \in T$ where $T \subset \mathbb{R}$.  The space $S$ is the **state space** of the process, and it could be discrete or continuous. If $T=\mathbb{N}$ then $X_t$ is called a **discrete time** stochastic process, and if $T$ is some interval in $\mathbb{R}$, then $X_t$ is referred to as a **continuous time** stochastic process.

A stochastic process with the [Markov property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_property) is called either a **Markov process** or a **Markov chain**.  (It seems more natural to call them the former, but Wikipedia uses the latter.) To be sure, the Markov property states that for any $A \in \Sigma$ and for each $s,t \in T$ with $s<t$, 
$$
P(X_t \in A \mid \mathcal{F}_s) = P(X_t \in A \mid X_s)
$$ where $\mathcal{F}_t$ is the filtration of the process up to time $s$.  This definition makes perfect sense for $T$ being a discrete or continuous set of times and for $S$ being a discrete or continuous state space.    For Markov processes the above classification of stochastic processes is nicely summarized in the following [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Introduction).  This basic framework can be used to classify all sorts of Markov processes including: [random walks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk), [Brownian motions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion), [Poisson processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_process), [birth-death processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birth%E2%80%93death_process), [diffusion processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_process), [jump diffusion processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_diffusion) and [branching processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_process).  For an intro to Markov processes, check out:

- Kirkwood, J. R. **Markov Processes.** Vol. 20. CRC Press, 2015.

Answer (score 5):

These terms (Markov chain / Markov process) seems to be mostly interchangeable, especially if one cares to specify whether the time is discrete or continuous. I would prefer "chain" to mean discrete time, and "process" to mean continuous time, but this is not a strict convention.

Also, how these terms are used in the Math subject classification:

http://www.ams.org/msc/msc2010.html?t=&s=markov&btn=Search&ls=Ct